# Uncaught TypeError: view.css is not a function

Tags: jquery, html, css, typeerror

I am trying to scroll div using button. I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27313480/scroll-div-content-horizontally-using-left-and-right-arrow-in-jquery) solution to resolve my problem. However I am getting error `Uncaught TypeError: view.css is not a function`. I added jquery plugins but still got this error.

Here is my code

```
<div class="bstimeslider">
<div id="rightArrow"></div>
    <div id="viewContainer">
        <div id="tslshow">
        <?php foreach($activity_data as $list):?>        
         <div class="bktibx">
          <div>
           <?php 
           if (isset( $list['coverimage']) && $list['coverimage']!=""){
            echo '<img src="'.$list["coverimage"].'" height="90" width="80" >';
          }else {
            echo '<img src="'.WEBSITE_URL.'views/site/activity_placeholder.png" height="90" width="80" >';
          } ?>
       </div>
     <div>
     <h4><a style="font-size: 20px;font-weight: bold;color:#48a4ca" href="<?php echo WEBSITE_URL ;?>site/eventDetail/<?php echo $list['_id']; ?>"><?php echo $list['title']; ?> </a></h4>
  <?php
  $ro= strlen($list['description']);
    if($ro >100){
      $small = substr($list['description'], 0, 100);
      echo  $small."...";
    } else {
      echo   strip_tags($list['description']);
    }
  ?>    
 </div>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
    </div>
    <div id="leftArrow"></div>
</div>
```

and jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var view = $("#tslshow").attr('id');
    var move = "100px";
    var sliderLimit = -750

    $("#rightArrow").click(function(){
      var currentPosition = parseInt(view.css("left"));
      if (currentPosition >= sliderLimit) 
       view.stop(false,true).animate({left:"-="+move},{ duration: 400})
    });
    $("#leftArrow").click(function(){
      var currentPosition = parseInt(view.css("left"));
      if (currentPosition < 0) 
        view.stop(false,true).animate({left:"+="+move},{ duration: 400});
   });
</script>
```

When i click on button I got error saying `Uncaught TypeError: view.css is not a function`.

Comment: `view` is not a jquery object. Wrap it in `$(view)` to access jquery lib methods.

Comment: while you use Id you don't need to use `var view = $("#tslshow").attr('id');` enough to use `var view = $("#tslshow");`

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef It showing me error `$  is not defined`

Comment: *$ is not defined* this error mean jquery is not included .. but its unlogic to get *Uncaught TypeError: view.css is not a function* then you get *$ is not defined* if jquery not included you should get *$ is not defined* first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1st:** You need to be sure to include jquery if you don't have jquery file you can use this line on `<head>` or before `</body>`

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**2nd:** You need to wrap your code after document ready .. like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   // code here
});
```

**3rd:** About your code

```
var view = $("#tslshow").attr('id'); // will output tslshow string not an object and while you use id you can just use `var view = $("#tslshow");`
```

about `view.css("left")` may be you need to set left to your element on css so if you decide to use `view = $("#tslshow").attr('id');` you will use `$('#'+view).css('left')` and if you will use `var view = $("#tslshow");` you will use `view.css('left');`

Answer (score 1):

replace this

```
var currentPosition = parseInt(view.css("left"));
```

with

```
var currentPosition = parseInt($(view).css("left"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code

```
var currentPosition = parseInt($("#tslshow").css("left"));
```

**or**

```
var view = "#tslshow";
var currentPosition = parseInt($(view).css("left"));
```

**or**

```
var currentPosition = parseInt($(view).css("left"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `var view = $("#tslshow").attr('id');` at Line no 1 to

`var view = $("#tslshow");`

You don't need the actual id. You just need a jQuery object to perform .css function call.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I found my solution. I need to use some jquery plugins.

`<script src="<?=WEBSITE_URL?>views/theme/_layout/js/animations/animate.js"></script>`
`<script src="<?=WEBSITE_URL?>views/theme/_layout/js/viewport/jquery.viewport.js"></script>`

That's all required to solve it